# MySQL remove string between brackets

Tags: mysql

How to remove  characters between two brackets and brackets. For example

```
Let it [Am]be, let it [C/G]be, let it [F]be, let it [C]be
[C]Whisper words of [G]wisdom, let it [F]be [C/E] [Dm] [C]
```

I want above string to

```
Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be
Whisper words of wisdom, let it be
```

I tried below code but it is only remove first brackets.

```
REPLACE(lyric, SUBSTRING(lyric, LOCATE('[', lyric), LENGTH(lyric) - LOCATE(']', 
REVERSE(lyric)) - LOCATE('[', lyric) + 2), ''))
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0, so you can use new functions like REGEXP_REPLACE()?

Comment: `LOCATE()` only returns the location of the first match. You can't use that method to do multiple replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 has a new function [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Demo:

```
mysql> set @s = 'Let it [Am]be, let it [C/G]be, let it [F]be, let it [C]be';

mysql> select regexp_replace(@s, '\\[[^]]*\\]', '@') as result;
+------------------------------------------------+
| result                                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Let it @be, let it @be, let it @be, let it @be |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I used `'@'` as the replacement text so it was more clear that the replacement worked multiple times. But you can replace the pattern with `''` to just remove it.

If you're using an earlier version of MySQL that doesn't have this function, I recommend that you upgrade. MySQL 8.0 has been the current version since 2018.

If you can't upgrade yet, then I recommend you solve this by fetching the string into your client application, perform string substitutions, and then UPDATE the new string back into the database. This is inconvenient, but a SQL-only solution is also inconvenient.

Comment: thanks. it is working. I change a little bit because I want to delete the character between two brackets. REGEXP_REPLACE(lyric, '\\[[^]]*\\]', '')